# Pivot or Transpose a table in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data

```
+------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| Name | Group | Limit1W | Limit1M | Limit3M |
+------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| Bob  | A     |     100 |      50 |       0 |
| Bob  | B     |     100 |      50 |       0 |
| Alex | A     |      20 |      50 |       0 |
| Alex | B     |       0 |       0 |       0 |
+------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want to get

```
+------+-------+---------+-------+
| Name | Group |  Game   | Limit |
+------+-------+---------+-------+
| Bob  | A     | Limit1W |   100 |
| Bob  | A     | Limit1M |    50 |
| Bob  | A     | Limit3M |     0 |
| Bob  | B     | Limit1W |   100 |
| Bob  | B     | Limit1M |    50 |
| Bob  | B     | Limit3M |     0 |
| Alex | A     | Limit1W |    20 |
| Alex | A     | Limit1M |    50 |
| Alex | A     | Limit3M |     0 |
| Alex | B     | Limit1W |     0 |
| Alex | B     | Limit1M |     0 |
| Alex | B     | Limit3M |     0 |
+------+-------+---------+-------+
```

I have tried using pivot_table but I keep getting:
typeError can only concatentante list (not "tuple") to list, even though the limits only contains numbers

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html is the function you want.

Comment: perfect, thanks alot

Comment: Perhaps post your solution as an answer in case other people have a similar question.